# Can you run multiple operations with Merge command in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a merge command using MS SQL Server 2014 to sync two tables together. I want to track each of the updates in a History table. I am getting an error when I write the `INSERT INTO` statement inside `WHEN MATCHED`.

Is it possible to get the rows that are being updated without using triggers? I'm trying to keep all the operations in the stored procedure.

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 71
Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'.
Expecting AND, OR, or THEN



    BEGIN TRAN;
    MERGE TestTable1 AS dst
    USING TestTable2 AS src
    ON ( dst.ID = src.ID )
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
            INSERT  ( ID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName) VALUES ( src.ID, src.LastName, src.FirstName, src.MiddleName)
    WHEN MATCHED AND  src.LastName <> dst.LastName
            OR src.FirstName <> dst.FirstName
            OR src.MiddleName <> dst.MiddleName
            UPDATE SET dst.LastName = src.LastName, dst.FirstName = src.FirstName, dst.MiddleName = src.MiddleName
            INSERT INTO HistoryTable (ID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName) VALUES (dst.ID, dst.LastName, dst.FirstName, dst.MiddleName)
    OUTPUT  $action
            , inserted.*
            , deleted.*;
    COMMIT   TRAN;
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. What is the error message you receive? It is absolutely possible to get the rows updated without triggers, your output should do that for you.

Comment: You might want to output into a table though

Comment: The insert into the `HistoryTable` should either be outside the merge or you should rearrange the current structure to use `OUTPUT INTO`